# 4 way connectivity chain code to 8 connectivity chain code

Tags: python, image-processing

I feel like this should be trivial, but I am having the hardest time converting a 4 way connected border chain code to 8 way. For example, if I had a border chain code (32323232333000101010) and wanted to convert it to 8 way, I would remove some of the redundant pixels by inserting 5's. I can clearly see the unnecessary pixels when I draw it out, but I am looking for the actual pattern so I can code it. Thanks

Comment: I suggest to show the drawing, which pixels you consider redundant, and the desired result for that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are different ways of defining chain codes, let’s assume that the 4-connected chain code uses 0 for a step to the right, 1 for a step up, 2 for a step left, etc. And the 8-connected one also uses 0 for a step to the right, 1 for a step right-up, 2 for up, etc.

Let’s assume also that the chain code encodes a closed boundary by tracing it clockwise.

The first step is to convert each 4-connected step into an 8-connected step, which is accomplished simply by multiplying by 2 (0->0, 1->2, 2->4, 3->6).

The second step is to simplify the 4-connected steps forming a right angle and producing a concave portion of the outline; these must be replaced by a diagonal step.

For example a step right (0) followed by a step down (6) would be convex, and should be preserved, but a step right (0) followed by a step up (2) would be concave and should be replaced by a single step right-up (1). Thus: 02->1, 24->3, 46->5, 60->7.

I implemented this in the DIPlib library, you can see the code [on GitHub](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/1918cbcb89feac292689d02ecc2ab99326771851/src/measurement/chain_code.cpp#L26).